# ¿Cómo usar una función que devuelve un puntero?

Tags: c++, punteros

Estoy resolviendo un ejercicio y no entiendo exactamente cómo estaría funcionando esta función que devuelve un puntero de tipo `char`.

```
char *carga(void)
{
    char cadena[30];

    cout<<"Digite una palabra: ";
    fflush(stdin); 
    cin.getline(cadena, 30, '\n');

    return &cadena[0];
}
```

¿Cómo podría invocarlo o transferirlo a otra variable en mi función `main`?

```
int main()
{
    int op;
    char cadena[30];

    cout << *carga();

    strcpy(cadena, carga());

    cout<<cadena<<endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

PSDT: El ejercicio nos pide que usemos la funcion tal como esta ahi `char *carga(void)`

Comment: Tienes un problema. La variable local `cadena` deja de existir cuando sales de la función. Por lo tanto no es buena idea devolver la dirección de memoria a una variable local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quiero saber como funcion el retorno de puntero de tipo char**

Podemos empezar por el principio. Veamos un ejemplo sencillo:

```
int func()
{
    int to_return;
    std::cin >> to_return;
    return to_return;
}

int main()
{
    int valor = func();
    std::cout << valor;
}
```

Esta función devuelve un entero, el cual ha sido introducido por el usuario.

¿Cómo funciona el `return` aquí? Simplemente se copia el valor de `to_return`.

Pues con los punteros sucede exactamente lo mismo. Un puntero no es más que una variable que almacena direcciones de memoria. Así, al retornar un puntero lo único que hace el programa es devolver una dirección de memoria.

**Tambien quiero saber como puedo invocar esa cadena de caracteres que introduzco en una funcion y poder invocar en mi funcion main**

Ya hemos dicho que los punteros no son más que variables que almacenan direcciones de memoria. Así, dada una función que devuelva un puntero tu puedes hacer 2 cosas con dicho puntero:

- Limitarte a copiar la direción de memoria.
- Clonar el contenido de la memoria a la que referencia el puntero.

Dicho con código:

```
char* func()
{
    static char to_return[100];
    std::cin >> to_return;
    return to_return;
}

int main()
{
    char * ptr = func(); // Copiamos la dirección de memoria
    std::cout << ptr << '\n';

    char buffer[100];
    strcpy(buffer, func()); // Clonamos el contenido de la memoria
    std::cout << buffer << '\n';

    // Importante!!!
    std::cout << ptr << '\n';
}
```

La diferencia entre ambos usos es que el primero, al usar memoria compartida, es sensible a los cambios que se hagan en dicha región de memoria. Esto es independiente del punto en el que se hagan dichos cambios. Por esta razón el último `puts` es capaz de mostrar el último texto introducido por el usuario

Un ejemplo en la vida real podría ser la pizarra de clase, todos los asistentes ven la misma pizarra y los cambios que en la misma realice el profesor podrán ser observados por todos ellos.

**Punteros desreferenciados**

Si comparas el ejemplo que te he puesto con el que figura en la pregunta se ve una diferencia fundamental.

En tu caso, la variable `cadena` **no es estática**. Esto es un problema, ya que `cadena` es una variable local, lo que significa que cuando la ejecución sale de `carga`, la memoria asociada a `cadena` pasa a estar disponible para otras variables, por lo que su contenido podría cambiar en cualquier momento.

Hay que tener mucho cuidado con esto. No puedes devoler una dirección de memoria de una variable local. De la misma manera tampoco deberías devolver un puntero sobre el que has ejecutado `free`:

```
int * ptr = (int*)malloc(100 * sizeof(int);
// ...
free(ptr);

return ptr; // <<--- ERROR!!!
```

**I/O C++**

No conviene mezclar usos de I/O propios de C con los propios de C++:

```
fflush(stdin);          // stdin - C
cin.getline(/* ... */); // cin   - C++
```

En primer lugar, `fflush` **no debería usarse con `stdin`. Esta función está diseñada para ser utilizada únicamente con *streams*  **de salida**. El comportamiento de esta función cuando se le pasa un *stream*  de entrada es indeterminado, lo que quiere decir que, dependiendo del compilador, puede funcionar, puede no funcionar o puede dar error.

Por otro lado hay que tener en cuenta que si bien `stdin` y `cin` hacen referencia, por defecto, a la entrada estándar, son mecanismos diferentes. Cada uno procesa la información a su manera.

Sucede que por defecto ambos mecanismos están sincronizados, por eso, en principio, podríamos mezclar usos de `stdin` y `cin`. Esta sincronización, sin embargo, tiene un precio y hace que la I/O en C++ sea mucho más lenta que en C.

Lo delicado de este asunto es que dicha sincronización puede desactivarse en cualquier momento ejecutando la siguiente línea:

```
std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
```

Desde ese momento `stdio` y `cin` irán cada uno a su aire y las llamadas a `cin` serán bastante más rápidas que las propias de `scanf` (algo lógico por otro lado).

Por este motivo y también por claridad, yo evitaría usar en un mismo programa `stdio` e `iostream`.

Si necesitas limpiar `cin` puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu función devuelve un dato puntero tipo char. La función en cuestión rellena la variable interna la cual se aloja en la memoria y tu función devuelve la dirección en memoria o un puntero que apunta a la dirección en memoria de dicha variable ya llena.

Luego se copia con la función `strcpy()` la otra cadena y posteriormente se imprime.

El código sería algo así:

```
int main()
{
    char cadenita[] = "hola mundo";
    char* cadena[30] =  {&cadenita[0]};

    char otraCadena[30];

    strcpy_s(otraCadena, *cadena);
    cout << otraCadena << endl;

    return 0;
}
```